# Why many scripts check variable equality using [ "x$variable" = "xSomething" ]

Tags: shell, conditional-statements

Title basically says it all. An example of aforementioned code from kafka's "kafka-run-class.sh":

```
if [ "x$GC_LOG_ENABLED" = "xtrue" ]; then
  GC_LOG_FILE_NAME=$DAEMON_NAME$GC_FILE_SUFFIX
  KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps "
fi
```

This checks if variable GC_LOG_ENABLED is exactly "true", as this is the only way for "x$GC_LOG_ENABLED" to evaluate to "xtrue". But this is pointless, since this:

```
[ "$GC_LOG_ENABLED" = "true" ]
```

has exactly the same meaning as far as I know. I can see point in it only if it was written as follows:

```
[ x$GC_LOG_ENABLED = xtrue ]
```

(note lack of quotes). If it wasn't for starting "x", we would get from:

```
[ $GC_LOG_ENABLED = true ]
```

the following:

```
[ = true ]
```

which makes no sens. But if parentheses are used, we get:

```
[ '' = 'true' ]
```

so everything is ok. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Asked (without quotes) [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136628/67134) and answered best [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137483/67134). Though the comments on the accepted answer cover some of those same details also.

Comment: Ha, thanks for information. I wonder if there is a way for searching for this question - it bugged me for some time already but I had hard time looking for this, mainly because it's symbols upon symbols...

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/ might work better for this (though I haven't always had much luck with it). Shell portability guides talk about some of it (like autoconf's [Portable Shell Programming](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Portable-Shell.html#Portable-Shell) section). The POSIX spec's [Application Usage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16) section for the `test` command also talks about it a little.